# Sonar Lint eclipse plugin project report

Tags: sonarlint, sonarlint-eclipse

I have sonar lint eclipse plugin installed on my eclipse. The plugin is working perfectly, however I need to run the sonar checks not only on a single file, but on the whole project.

I did my research and I learned that the CLI interface of sonar can achieve such thing and can even generate some HTML report, however for one reason or the other the documentation is not so obvious about it.

Any help or even a direction is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the IDEs, SonarLint focuses on analyzing files as they are edited, to catch issues as early as possible. The idea is to prevent new issues to be introduced, more than to detect existing problems.

SonarLint CLI is primarily designed to check the issues on projects that are not using the supported IDEs, before committing code.

Analyzing all files is not currently supported but it might be implemented later at some point. Currently, we are concentrated in making SonarLint for Eclipse as efficient as possible in analyzing code as it is edited.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I hope you would be able to do so, as reporting is an integral part of the tool that is used more than often specially in code reviews.